# SVAR Historical decomposition

Tags: econometrics, dsge, r

Does anyone know how to do VAR historical decomposition of a series in R?

Comment: Perhaps this question is a better fit for stackoverflow?

Comment: Unless the question is about the economics or econometrics of the VAr decomposition, then the question should be in stackoverflow or an R list.